# How to calculate prediction error in a LSTM keras

Tags: keras, time-series, predictive-modeling, regression, forecast

I have an LSTM which I have constructed and run in keras using python.  I use this model to predict $n$ points into the future for a time series forecasting problem.

When I use a method such as ARIMA to make the forecast I am able to generate prediction errors for my predictions as the model is fit by minimising the MLE using AIC for example.

Is there a way that is currently supported in keras for me to generate prediction errors for my regression predictions?  If there isn't, is there a way that I can calculate it myself?

Comment: Do you want confidence intervals?

Comment: I think so, you'll have to forgive me that I am not quite sure on what the difference between a confidence interval and prediction error would be.  A lot of the time the terminology seems to be used interchangeably.  I would like to be able to say something like the model says in week two the quantity will be $\hat{y}$ and we are 99% sure the actual value $y$ will be in the range $\hat{y}_{\text{lower}}$-$\hat{y}_{\text{upper}}$.  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use the technique explained in the article ["Dropout as a Bayesian Approximation: Representing Model Uncertainty in Deep Learning"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.02142.pdf)

Very briefely the technique consists of applying [dropout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolutional_neural_network#Dropout) for training and **predictions**.

In Keras this can be easily applied passing the `training` argument in the call of the Dropout layer.

```
import keras

input  = ...
x      = keras.layer.Dense(100)(input)
dp     = keras.layer.Dropout(0.5)(x, training=True)
output = keras.layer.Activation('relu')

model = keral.Model(input, output)
```

During prediction you get the mean and standard deviations:

```
T = 1000   # Do 1000 predictions to estimate uncertainty
predictions = np.array([model.predict(X_test)] for _ in range(T)])

pred_mean = results.mean(axis=0)
pre_std   = results.std(axis=0)
```

You can increase (or descrease) `T` if you need more (or less) precision.

Comment: A previous answer to a similar question: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/24403/prediction-interval-around-lstm-time-series-forecast?rq=1

Comment: Thanks for the response, I’ll read through the article and see how it goes.